# program panics after catching an error in main block. panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

I am new to golang. My program panics after I try to catch an error in the main block after getting location defined.  I have read somewhere, adding defer.close() might help, but again the compiler says no such definition exists in your struct Help me resolve it.

```
type IPInfo struct {

    IP string

    Hostname string

    City string
    Country string

    Loc string
    Org string
    Postal string
}
func main() {
        ip := getLocalIpv4()
        location, err := ForeignIP(ip)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error bro")
        }

    fmt.Println("ip address of this machine is ", location.IP)
    fmt.Println(" city of this machine is ", location.City)

}

// MyIP provides information about the public IP address of the client.
func MyIP() (*IPInfo, error) {
    return ForeignIP("")
}

// ForeignIP provides information about the given IP address,
// which should be in dotted-quad form.
func ForeignIP(ip string) (*IPInfo, error) {
    if ip != "" {
        ip += "/" + ip
    }
    response, err := http.Get("http://ipinfo.io" + ip + "/json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var ipinfo IPInfo
    if err := json.Unmarshal(contents, &ipinfo); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &ipinfo, nil
}

// retrieves ip address of local machine
func getLocalIpv4() string {
    host, _ := os.Hostname()
    addrs, _ := net.LookupIP(host)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        if ipv4 := addr.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%s", ipv4)
        }
    }
    return "localhost"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ForeignIP()` returns `*IPInfo` which is a struct of pointer type but you're getting error from this line of code `response, err := http.Get("http://ipinfo.io" + ip + "/json")` which is failed due to below error:

> dial tcp: lookup ipinfo.io172.16.11.115: no such host.

Then you return `nil` over there like.

```
   if err != nil {
            return nil , err
   }
```

And you access the value of nil as:

```
location, err := ForeignIP(ip)
fmt.Println("ip address of this machine is ", location.IP)
fmt.Println(" city of this machine is ", location.City)
```

So `nil` value has not any `IP` or `City` variable that is why it panic. So you need to return struct which is of pointer type then you can access the variable `IP` and `City` from `location` response, here I'm modifying the code.

```
func ForeignIP(ip string) (*IPInfo, error) {
    var ipinfo IPInfo
    if ip != "" {
        ip += "/" + ip
    }
    response, err := http.Get("http://ipinfo.io" + ip + "/json")
    if err != nil {
        return &ipinfo , err
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return &ipinfo, err
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(contents, &ipinfo); err != nil {
        return &ipinfo, err
    }
    return &ipinfo, nil
}
```